# Replace text after special character

Tags: regex, powershell

I have string which should to be change from numbers to text in my case variable is:

```
$string = '18.3.0-31290741.41742-1'
```

I want to replace everything after '-' to be "-SNAPSHOT" and when perform echo `$string` to show information below. I tried with `LastIndexOf()`, `Trim()` and other things but seems not able to manage how to do it.

Expected result:

```
PS> echo $string
18.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Maybe that can be the light of the correct way, but when have two '-' is going to replace the last one not the first which can see:

```
$string = "18.3.0-31290741.41742-1" -replace '(.*)-(.*)', '$1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: Actually maybe found solution for myself:
`'18.3.0-31290741.41742-1' -replace '^(\d+.\d+.\d+).*','$1-SNAPSHOT'`

Answer (score 2):

`.*` is a greedy match, meaning it will produce the longest matching (sub)string. In your case that would be everything up to the *last* hyphen. You need either a non-greedy match (`.*?`) or a pattern that won't match hyphens (`^[^-]*`).

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> '18.3.0-31290741.41742-1' -replace '(^.*?)-.*', '$1-SNAPSHOT'
18.3.0-SNAPSHOT
PS C:\> '18.3.0-31290741.41742-1' -replace '(^[^-]*)-.*', '$1-SNAPSHOT'
18.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

By using a positive lookbehind assertion (`(?<=...)`) you could eliminate the need for a capturing group and backreference:

```
PS C:\> "18.3.0-31290741.41742-1" -replace '(?<=^.*?-).*', 'SNAPSHOT'
18.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Select-String` and an regular expression to match the pattern, then pass the match to `ForEach-Object` (commonly shorthanded with alias `%`) to construct the final string:

```
$string = "18.3.0-31290741.41742-1" | Select-String -pattern ".*-.*-" | %{ "$($_.Matches.value)SNAPSHOT" }
$string
```

Comment: Whilst your answer is technically valid, it is good practice to explain your answers as well as just including the code. Especially when you add code that wasn't included in the original question eg: `%{ "$($_.Matches.value)SNAPSHOT" }` Here you've used an alias and not explained why `$_.Matches` is used or works. Doing this improves the quality of your answer and helps anyone who finds it in the future understand it :)